# What does "Whether it's 2026 or 2028 or 2030 matters less" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean **Whichever year, 2026 or 2028 or 2030, is not important**?

Yifan Zhang, an associate professor of economics at the Chinese University of Hong Kong, didn't have an exact guess for the year China's economy will become the world's biggest. "Whether it's 2026 or 2028 or 2030 matters less," Zhang said. "On the day when China becomes the largest economy again, it signals there's a shift of power between the East and West."

Source:https://fortune.com/2021/01/18/chinas-2020-gdp-world-no-1-economy-us/

Comment: Yes, that's what it means. Mr Zhang didn't say what the date matters less _than_, but presumably he meant 'it matters less than the fact that it will happen'.

Comment: China's economy will become the world's biggest. What year? Not important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that it means that the fact of the shift of power that will happen soon is more important than the exact year it will happen.